Issues with Google Maps API Directions Not Returning Transit Data
I am encountering an issue with the Google Maps Directions API when trying to fetch directions using the transit mode. Despite specifying transit mode in the URL, the API often returns data for driving mode instead.
Here is the URL I am using:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?key=*API_KEY_HERE*&destination=place_id:ChIJMZG7QYYFdkgRdJlpSt0DxJk&mode=TRANSIT&origin=place_id:ChIJmQX7xXMDdkgREouGIsD6o74&departure_time=now

I have noticed that sometimes it works when I change "mode=TRANSIT" to lowercase like this: "mode=transit", and it provides the correct transit data sometimes. However, most of the time, it still does not work and returns driving data instead.
Has anyone faced a similar issue or have any insights on why this might be happening and how to consistently retrieve transit data?
Thank you in advance for your help!
I am expecting to fetch the data for transit data not driving.
Edit: Bug report

Mode should be transit not TRANSIT. It looks like a bug and you reported it in the issue tracker so Google should get back to you.
